# How to twist particle hair guide along a curve?

Tags: particles, hair

First I have an emitter and one curve,then I use bevel to create the shape and convert it to mesh.Using the hair guide addon I convert the mesh volume to particle hair guide.

[image]

[image]

How can I twist the whole bunch of hair guides along a curve ?

Edit:Just find out that setting curve guide for force field works for me.But can we use a map for a particle system telling it which part should be affected by the force field like density?

Answer (score 1):

A *Force Field* of type *Curve Guide* can bend particles along a curve. The force field globally affects **all** particles systems and all particles. But you can limit the influence in the *Particle Settings* > *Field Weights* > *Effector Collection*. Select an empty collection to exclude all force fields.

Let's say you want to make pigtails. For this, you need 2 particle systems (for left and right), 2 density groups, and 2 collections each with one *Curve Guide* force field in it.